# Share FAQs on social media

Tags: wordpress, socialshare

I'm using the [FAQ WD Plugin](https://web-dorado.com/products/wordpress-faq-wd.html) for FAQ page of my website. I want to add social share to individual questions. The functionality should be that if a user shares an FAQ on any social media network, the link should be to the FAQ page with that particular question open.

Can anyone suggest some how to achieve the goal?

Comment: whats an issue here?

Comment: The user just get redirected to the FAQ page but the question is not open. Furthermore, while sharing I wnat the content box to show the question, but the content of the FAQ page is getting shown there.

Comment: can you please share a url with me?

Comment: [link](http://upsbazaar.in/faq/) FAQ Page.
In the first question under the UPS section, I have added social share links but they don't behave as desired

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: I didn't see share button over there.

Comment: ok I got it what was an issue.Your plugin is forward whole thing in share.

Comment: What do I need to do to get the feature I need?

Comment: You have to customise plugin as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

*faq_wd_content.php*

```
    <span class="faqwd_share_links">
<a  href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>" class="faqwd_fb" data-original-title="Share on Facebook">
</a>
<a  href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>" class="faqwd_gpluse" data-original-title="Share on Google+ ">
</a>
<a  href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID)?>" class="faqwd_twitter" data-original-title="Tweet It">
</a>
</span>
```

Here You get all content that shared on Social.You can get modified otherwise hire someone for customisation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll insert the code and try. I'll let you know about the outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I edited the share link to contain the ID as a query string. Then on load of the page, I added a check if the URL contains an ID query param.

If the url has a query param 'ID', then in the particular FAQ with that ID, I added the 'opened' CSS class to open it.